# SQL Server Date Conversion from a specific format to a different exact date format

Tags: sql-server, c#-4.0, datetime-format

I have a particular situation that I can't quite figure out.

I have a field in a SQL table that is saved as a DATETIME in the following format:

```
2016-11-26 00:00:00
```

This is all good-and-well, except that I need it in `dd/MM/yyyy` format.

I don't want to use the `CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @dateField, 103)` function in SQL because I want a DATE format, not a STRING format.

I export a result DataTable to Excel using the EPPlus library and I need the date fields in the export in this exact format.

I tried:

- `FORMAT(@dateField, 'dd/MM/yyyy', 'en-gb')` as well as casting this back to a DATE type.  It still implicitly converts to VARCHAR or NVARCHAR
- Casting @dateField to DATE and SMALLDATETIME
- Using C# to try and convert this to a date in the correct format.  `DateTime.ParseExact(dataTable.Rows[i]["DateField"].ToString(), "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`
- EPPlus column formatting: `workSheet.Column(19).Style.Numberformat.Format = "dd/MM/yyyy";`

I'm running out of options on this conversion because none of my attempts are working for a DateTime format.  Every path I've taken converts my value(s) back to a string.  Any assistance would be appreciated :)

Comment: Why are you calling `DateTime.ParseExact`? The value should already be a `DateTime`, so just cast it to that and *then* call `ToString`. And if you want a specific format, you *are* asking for a string, not a `DateTime` value.

Comment: DateTime has **NO** format. It's a binary value, just like .NET's DateTime or bool, or decimal. You don't need to convert anything. Just use a parameterized query or ORM and pass the DateTime values as DateTime parameters. EPPlus doesn't need any specific formats either - dates in Excel use the OADate binary format and EPPlus converts DateTime to it directly. How Excel displays a date, depends on the specific column style which *can* be confusing

Comment: @JonSkeet I tried a regular Parse as well as a direct cast.  The Parse didn't change the format and the direct cast threw an InvalidCastException.  Changing the type in SQL, even without the conversion saves the value in the spreadsheet as a number.  I'm expecting 22/03/2011, but the cell value is 40624 :(

Comment: @GrammatonCleric which is 1000% correct. That's exactly how dates are stored in Excel. That's an offset from 1899-12-31. Change the cell style to a Date format and you'll see your date.

Comment: If the direct cast threw an exception, then you weren't selecting a `DateTime` column appropriately... it's hard to give more help without more information, but the execution-time type of `dataTable.Rows[i]["DateField"]` should be `System.DateTime`. You should find out what it actually is.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a datetime column it's saved as binary representation of the date; it's only when rendered in a client application such as management studio is it rendered in some format.

So if you need it in a particular format you mean rendered as a string in that format. You can always convert back to a datetime (and should!) when saving back to the database. For example, you may want to trim the time part from a datetime before saving.

Comment: Fair conclusion, however, it's a 3rd-party system and I don't have permissions to change the code in such a way that I can post data to the database in a specific manner

Comment: Sorry if I'm, misunderstanding, but Sql Server will store the data in datetime as number representing the date, the format is ony important when examining/displaying the data, and of course when inserting/updating. It's always best to use a format that is unambiguous to Sql Server (say, 29 Nov 2016), but if your 3rd party system works with the format you're giving it you should be OK?

Comment: @GrammatonCleric most likely you confuse Excel's way of displaying dates for a SQL formatting problem. There is none. Dates in Excel are *always* stored as decimals (date offset + time fraction). This is displayed in different ways depending on the number format you choose. Some of them are considered "local" formats, resulting in different formats for different locales